# OAuth 2.0 refresh token for installed applications

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use Oauth 2.0 to access a Google API in an installed application. I want the user to give access only once and then use the refresh token to get new access tokens to work with the api.

The user uses this code to give permission to the application:

```
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
'client_secrets.json',
scope='https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/',
redirect_uri='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')


auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
webbrowser.open(auth_uri)

auth_code = raw_input('Introduce the code: ')

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)

f = file("Pass.txt", "w")
f.write(credentials.to_json())
f.close()
```

And then the aplication uses this other code every day to use the api:

```
f = open("Pass.txt", "r")
credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(f.read())
f.close()

client = gdata.apps.emailsettings.client.EmailSettingsClient(domain=domain_name)
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2TokenFromCredentials(credentials)
```

This code works for a week and then stops working throwing the following error:

```
gdata.client.Unauthorized: Unauthorized - Server responded with: 401, <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: Token not found</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: Token not found</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Does anybody now what is wrong with this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the token expires and the server returns the 401 you should use the `refresh` method on the credentials object to get a new access token and write that back in to storage, so you'd run:

```
f = open("Pass.txt", "r")
credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(f.read())
f.close()

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials.refresh(http)

f = file("Pass.txt", "w")
f.write(credentials.to_json())
f.close()
```